# Contact Form 7 submission does not complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a Content Form 7 Version 3.8.1 form which seems to function perfectly in that the validation events all work and when submit is clicked the console shows no error, a 200 response comes back from the post but no success message displays and the ajax-loader continues to display indefinitely.

No email is received either.

The form can be seen at http://peteshighway.com/public-meeting-comment-form/

Here are the network and console tabs after submission:

[image: network tab]

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fatal error in the theme you are using. When I checked the response in firebug console, I got the following error

**Fatal error**:  Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in **/home/content/s/b/r/sbrenan/html/peteshighway.com/wp-content/themes/peteshwy/functions.php** on line **96**

Either you fix this or contact with the theme support team.

Comment: Thank you.  I had no idea the FireBug console would see any differences.  So much for my monogamous Chrome testing...

Comment: Its similar in chrome console. Once you click the link in the 1st column, it will expand showing more information. There you need to check the Response tab. I just checked on your site and its working now.

Comment: Yep, fixed the syntax error my predecessor had left for me!  Thanks!